# How to remove a Shell Folder Shortcut in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

As the title says, I'm trying to remove a shell shortcut from windows 10. Just to clarify: `Run...`, type, `shell:windows`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Standard behavior is to open file explorer to `%windir%`. I want it to not do that. My reason for wanting to do so, is because it bypasses the NoDrives restriction from the registry, allowing access to the hard drive, even when it's locked out.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\
```

The above folder contains a list of guid's that the internet said correspond to these shell shortcuts. I look through them, found the one that seemed to correspond to `shell:windows` and deleted it and all subkeys. But that did not work.

How could I get rid of these? or what else could I do to secure the hard drive from a resourceful user?

Thanks